# selecting programmatically a vtk widget

Tags: c++, image-processing, visual-c++, mfc, vtk

I am struggle to achieve basic functionality on VTK widget: selecting and deleting.

I have a **vtkDistanceWidget**. And after I created, I intend to click on his handle (see image below):

[image]

in order to *select it, to modify it and eventually to delete it*. The fact is that I don't know when this widget is selected. If I use a picker:

```
vtkPropPicker* pPicker = vtkPropPicker::New();
pPicker->Pick(nPosition[0], nPosition[1], 0, m_pRenderer);
TRACE("Pointer: %p\n", pPicker->GetProp3D());
```

the TRACE is not executed when I click on widget handles, but it is visible when I click anywhere in the rest.

Also, second attempt, I have tried with callbacks:

```
void CVTKDoc::CreateDistanceWidget(CVTKView* pView)
{
vtkDistanceWidget* pDistanceWidget = vtkDistanceWidget::New();
pDistanceWidget->SetInteractor(pView->m_pInteractor);
// Create the default widget representation and set the label format
pDistanceWidget->CreateDefaultRepresentation();
static_cast<vtkDistanceRepresentation*>(pDistanceWidget->GetRepresentation())->SetLabelFormat(_T("%-#6.3g mm"));
// Allow the observer to access the widget
vtkCallbackCommand* pKeypressCallback = vtkCallbackCommand::New();
pKeypressCallback->SetCallback(&CVTKDoc::LeftButtonPressEvent);
pKeypressCallback->SetClientData(pDistanceWidget);
pDistanceWidget->GetInteractor()->AddObserver(vtkCommand::KeyPressEvent, pKeypressCallback);
pDistanceWidget->On();
// Add widget pointer to map to cleanup later
if (NULL != pDistanceWidget)
    InsertWidgetToMap(pView, pDistanceWidget);
pKeypressCallback->Delete();
}
```

and then (static method)

```
void CVTKDoc::KeypressCallbackFunction(vtkObject* caller, long unsigned int eventId, void* clientData, void* callData)
{
CVTKDoc* pDoc = CVTKDoc::GetDoc();
vtkRenderWindowInteractor* pInteractor = static_cast<vtkRenderWindowInteractor*>(caller);
CString sKey = pInteractor->GetKeySym();
TRACE(">>>%s\n", sKey);
}
```

Every time when I press the left button, I see the TRACE, but **when I press the button on the widget handle**, the callback function *is not executed at all*, just like in the first solution.

How can I know when I click on widget handles ?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Did you look at vtk Examples (e.g. https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Widgets/LineWidget2/ ) ?